# Hierarchical routes in Yesod

Tags: routes, yesod

I'm trying to use hierarchial routes in Yesod (version 1.4.5.1), but apparently I'm doing something wrong. The relevant part of my `config/routes` files (I'm using the standard scaffolded site) looks like this:

```
/ HomeR GET
/about AboutR:
    / AboutIndexR GET
    /team AboutTeamR GET
/service ServiceR:
    / ServiceIndexR GET
    /newsletter ServiceNewsletterR GET
```

I get the following compile errors:

```
Foundation.hs:34:21
    Exception when trying to run compile-time code:
      Overlapping routes:
("HomeR", "AboutIndexR")
("HomeR", "ServiceIndexR")
("AboutIndexR", "ServiceIndexR")
```

Apparently Yesod doesn't understand that all three `/` are different paths!? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sites that work just like this, and it seems to work correctly. I also copied your routes snippet, which seems to pass the overlap check just fine. Are you sure that there's not some kind of issue with the indentation in your `config/routes`? If you're certain that's not the problem, perhaps you can upload the file itself somewhere for review.

Comment: This is weird. Although I'm absolutely positive that the indentation was ok, after some (unrelated?) changes and a complete reinstall of yesod everything works as expected... Thanks for confirming that my approach is/was ok.